# Errors in core application tests

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

When I bring up my server with the `--test-enable` flag, I'm getting errors in a bunch of tests from the core App tests.  Some examples are below

```
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: ERROR: test_period_state (odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period.TestPeriodState)
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\account\tests\test_account_move_closed_period.py", line 12, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\account\tests\account_test_classes.py", line 16, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tests\common.py", line 248, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 430, in enter_test_mode
2017-08-13 16:31:44,322 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.account.tests.test_account_move_closed_period: ` AssertionError

2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: ERROR: test_cost_invoicing (odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order.TestSaleOrder)
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: ` Test confirming a vendor invoice to reinvoice cost on the so
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\sale\tests\test_sale_common.py", line 9, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\account\tests\account_test_classes.py", line 16, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tests\common.py", line 248, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 430, in enter_test_mode
2017-08-13 16:31:44,405 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.sale.tests.test_sale_order: ` AssertionError

2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: ERROR: test_01_delivery_stock_move (odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move.StockMoveInvoice)
2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\delivery\tests\test_delivery_stock_move.py", line 9, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons\account\tests\account_test_classes.py", line 16, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\tests\common.py", line 248, in setUp
2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: `   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 430, in enter_test_mode
2017-08-13 16:31:44,434 18216 ERROR todo odoo.addons.delivery.tests.test_delivery_stock_move: ` AssertionError
```

I haven't changed any code in any of the core apps.  The apps that I have installed are

- Inventory Management
- Sales
- Discuss
- Invoicing
- Accounting and Finance

Do you know why these tests would be failing?  Is there anything additional that I have to do besides installing these Apps in order to get these tests to succeed?

Comment: Have you installed the demo data in your DB?

Comment: No, I didn't.  How do I do that?  I tried running `odoo-bin -d demo` and I can see a database named `demo` get created with pgAdmin, but I don't know how to populate its demo data, and I can't find an option on the web front end.  Additionally, when I open the Odoo web page and turn on Developer Tools, in the upper right it says `Administrator (odoo)`, so it looks like the web front end is using the `odoo` database instead of the `demo` database.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to run unit tests in Odoo your working database must have the demo data loaded.

Go to the database management page (`http://<IP>/web/database/manager`) and create a new database and make sure the *"Load demonstration data"* box is checked. This will fill in the database with some demonstration data that is needed for Odoo in order to run tests.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That worked perfectly.  One more question: during Odoo development, is it common practice to have one database per app or new feature that is being developed?

Comment: Not necessarily, working on the same db is fine, thanks to the way Odoo modules are built. However, if you're something complex and need to isolate it, working on a separate db for that app would certainly help :)